# How to pick xml from my local to server

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration, and I have developed an sample application also but my query is that I have an xml file which I am attaching , I want that this xml file is in folder named abc in my system, the name of this xml file is df.xml please advise how to make an spring integration program that will pick this xml file and will keep it on server at location /var/data , please advise on this

the content of the df.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" changeId="1" batchNo="Loyalty_TestData">
  <TRANSACTION transactionNo="1">
    <LOYALTY docNo="1">
      <CRUD>P</CRUD>
      <SCHEME_CODE>EMPLOYEE</SCHEME_CODE>
      <SCHEME_NAME>EMPLOYEE DISCOUNT</SCHEME_NAME>
      <SCHEME_TYPE>37002</SCHEME_TYPE>
      <REWARD_TYPE>40002</REWARD_TYPE>
      <REWARD_BY_LINE>1</REWARD_BY_LINE>
      <VALID_ATTEMPTS>3</VALID_ATTEMPTS>
      <LEGAL_TENDER>USD</LEGAL_TENDER>
      <DEC_PLC_SCHEME>0</DEC_PLC_SCHEME>
      <DEC_PLC_ALLOC>0</DEC_PLC_ALLOC>
      <LOG_TXNHEADER>0</LOG_TXNHEADER>
      <LOG_TXNLOYALTY>0</LOG_TXNLOYALTY>
      <LOG_TXNPOINTS>0</LOG_TXNPOINTS>
      <LOG_TXNDETAIL>0</LOG_TXNDETAIL>
      <LOG_TXNDTLLTY>0</LOG_TXNDTLLTY>
      <PARAMETERS> </PARAMETERS>
    </LOYALTY>
  </TRANSACTION>
</FILE>
```

Th idea was coming to mind that there should be buffered channel and from that buffered channel , outbound adapter will pick that xml and will keep it in queue but from the queue I have to put it ito server at location mentioned above please advise how to achieve that..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've give a little too much information in your question. It's not a good idea to give the IP address, username and password, there are some clever people around who might find that very interesting!

Also I suspect that your question is actually about file transfer, specifically how you get the file from your PC and onto a unix machine. I suggest you take a look at ftp and sftp, you can use command line tools to do this or there are plenty of GUI applications. If you are feeling particularly lazy and have a console open onto the unix machine you can even cut-and-paste, but it's not recommended (I do it though ;)